# Custom URL structure for Laravel

Tags: laravel

I would like to create a custom URL structure for my Laravel application.

Right now I have a structure like this:

1. mydomain.com/**products**/product-name - **ProductController**
2. mydomain.com/**articles**/article-name - **ArticleController**
3. mydomain.com/**users**/user-name - **UserController**

I would like to transform it like this:

1. mydomain.com/product-name - **ProductController**
2. mydomain.com/article-name - **ArticleController**
3. mydomain.com/user-name - **UserController**

*I already have slugs in common db table. It's not a problem to detect which controller should I use for "product-name".*

I want to know, what's the best practice in this case. Where can I put my logic which connects slug "product-name" to ProductController?

Should I use middleware or is there any other approach to do so?

Answer (score 0):

What you want, your can specify that in your web.php like

```
Route::get('user-{name}', 'UserController@show')->name('users.show');
```

and in UserController

```
function show(Request $request, User $name){
    return $name;
}
```

should work fine, but what about other end points like index, delete, edit etc?

What I feel it will be like

```
Route::delete('user-{name}', 'UserController@delete')->name('users.delete');
```

but what about `index()` ? and even in this case, `name` must be unique or it will create exceptional results.

May be if you will make it more clear, I may edit my answer according to that, but

I believe, you should follow route-model binding concept of Laravel, in stead of making too much customization. According to route-model binding concept

In your model

```
public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'name';
}
```

now, if you want to customize it more, you can use

**RouteServiceProvider.php** `boot()` method

```
public function boot()
{
    parent::boot();
    Route::bind('flat_member', function ($value) {
        return 'user-' . $value;
    });
}
```